# parent child relations in elasticsearch across indicies

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently on elasticsearch 5.6.X version of elasticsearch, I want to upgrade to the latest 7.x version.

I use a strategy where each index is a separate tenant

```
that is:
 - CLIENT-A data will be on INDEX-A
 - CLIENT-B data will be on INDEX-B
```

Each index contains multiple types (`student`, `faculty`, `class`), and has parent child relationships
that is:

- mapping type `student` will be on INDEX-A
- mapping type `class` will be on INDEX-A and be defined as the parent of `student`

What I interpreted from elastic.co's blog https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type is

- use one type per index
- parent child relations and queries (using has_parent, has_child) will only work when the type is on the same index

### Question

- Is my interpretation of what elastic correct ? If so what would be the part forward by which I can upgrade and still maintain relations

**limitations**

- In the real world I have multiple mapping types, each with parent relation. Student-Class is just an example
- In the real world I cannot have the parent docs duplicated per index,

```
Client A :
 - IndexA-Student : with student and class
 - IndexA-Faculty : with faculty and class

Client B :
 - IndexB-Student : with student and class
 - IndexB-Faculty : with faculty and class
```

Comment: you don't have to use different indexes for different types. It's just a performance improvement. In your case with the parent child relation, just use one index.

Comment: I think I missed an important detail in my question, I want to upgrade to 7.X version of elasticsearch which removes all notion of mapping types. Is using a single index still a valid option ?

Comment: You are correct..the old style _type has gone. Just add an extra field called 'docType' or similar, to replace it, and keep them all in one index. 
docType='parent'
docType='child'